# IEEE 754 Floating Point Representation

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, ieee-754, number-formatting, arithmetic-expressions

How do I convert from decimal to IEEE 745 Floating point single precision ?
I can work with small numbers like 0.5, 0.75, etc
My problem is that I've no idea what to do with smaller numbers.
For example,

12.1325 * 10^-13

Comment: What is your question? What problem are you having with "simaller numbers"?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the difficulty is the binary conversion and not the IEEE float encoding (since you say you know how to convert 0.5 and 0.75). For less straightforward examples, like 12.1325 * 10<sup>-13</sup>, I would use my [binary converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/)). To 70 places, 0.00000000000121325 is

0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000001010101010111111111100000001111...

Rounded (by hand) to 24 significant bits, that's
0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000010101010101111111111

From there, it's straitforward to encode this as a float.

Another way to do this is analytically (you'll need the help of a good arbitrary-precision calculator though, like [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)). Start by rewriting 12.1325 * 10<sup>-13</sup> as 121325/10<sup>17</sup>, and try to find the closest number with a 24-bit numerator and power of two denominator:

121325/10<sup>17</sup> = x/2<sup>n</sup>

x = (2<sup>n</sup> * 121325)/10<sup>17</sup>

You'll discover that n=63 gives you what you're after: x = 11190256.123714056749056 = 11190256 (when rounded to the nearest integer). (11190256 = 101010101011111111110000 in binary, and you'll see that matches the answer above.) When you normalize the float, you'll subtract 23 from the exponent, giving: 1.0101010101111111111 * 2<sup>-40</sup>

(For the latter method, see my article [Correct Decimal To Floating-Point Using Big Integers](http://www.exploringbinary.com/correct-decimal-to-floating-point-using-big-integers/).)